# How do I construct a dispform.axpx link to send to home page on close

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Within an email I have a link that opens the form in view for a document library item.  When they close the item, it automatically forwards the user to the default view of the library.

Is there a way when the user closes the item (assuming they use the link I provided in the email) that a different page could open ? Such as...

1-The default view would not open and an alternative view would open such as a view I created called pending items.axpx

OR

2-Have the Home page open instead of the default view of the document library.

From Googling it appears I need to amend the string of my email link, but not sure what I need to amend.

The current link is SireUrl/SharedDocs/Forms/dispform.aspx?ID=229

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible, you need to add a query string parameter `Source` in the url. In the email you send, append the below line to set as the default redirect url. It will then redirect the user to your desired page on click of Save and Cancel button.

1) redirect to different view:

```
https://SireUrl/SharedDocs/Forms/dispform.aspx?ID=229&Source=SireUrl/SharedDocs/Forms/pendingitems.aspx
```

2) redirect to home page:

```
https://SiteUrl/SharedDocs/Forms/dispform.aspx?ID=229&Source=SiteUrl
```